# Android add View for paint on phone into Activity

Tags: android

I have simple view class to draw paint into that, I don't have for that when I try to add it into activity by this way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BrushView view=new BrushView(this);
    setContentView(view);
    addContentView(view.btnEraseAll, view.params);
}
```

now unfortunately I can not be add this view into LinearLayout in activity

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <com.sample.app.Libraries.BrushViewClass
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My `BrushViewClass` :

```
public class BrushViewClass extends View {
    private Paint brush = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    public Button btnEraseAll;
    public LayoutParams params;

    public BrushViewClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
        brush.setAntiAlias(true);
        brush.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        brush.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        brush.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        brush.setStrokeWidth(10f);

        btnEraseAll = new Button(context);
        btnEraseAll.setText(UC.getString(R.string.redraw_again));
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        btnEraseAll.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_button_actions));
        btnEraseAll.setLayoutParams(params);
        btnEraseAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                path.reset();
                postInvalidate();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float pointX = event.getX();
        float pointY = event.getY();

        // Checks for the event that occurs
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);

            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        // Force a view to draw.
        postInvalidate();
        return false;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, brush);
    }
}
```

I have `LinearLayout` in `Activity` and I want to add it to that, for example:

```
BrushViewClass view=new BrushViewClass(this);
LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
myLinearLayout.addView(view.btnEraseAll, view.params);
```

Comment: What is happening? Is your View visible?

Comment: Do you want to add the whole BrushView or only the erase Button?

Comment: @joao2fast4u my view is visible and dont have any problem. i want to add BrushView class which extends from view into linearlayout in Activity

Comment: Then why are you using `myLinearLayout.addView(view.btnEraseAll, view.params);` instead of `myLinearLayout.addView(view, view.params);`

Comment: @joao2fast4u i have this widget into activity and i want to add this view into that, i dont like open ither activity and attach this view into that